# How to alter CSS for an inaccessible child class for an alert message component?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have created a textarea element with a maximum character limit. When the limit is reached, it should display an error message. I am using a pre-existing component called `lib-error-alert-message`. This is how the HTML code looks like -

```
<textarea class="my-text" rows="10" maxlength="500" [formControl]="textControl"> </textarea>
<lib-error-alert-message class="alert" *ngIf="(text | async) == 50" [alertMsg]="limitAlertMessage">
</lib-error-alert-message>
```

I have used this component elsewhere and it is working fine, however, in this particular page, the component has an internal class named "msgs" which has a margin-left property of -3rem.

[image]

This is causing the error alert and the textarea orientation to be askew.
While inspecting the element, if I uncheck the margin-left property then it looks correct.
I tried to create a class "alert" for the lib-error-alert-message and used the following code for that -

```
.alert {
margin-left: 0 !important;
width: fit-content;
}
```

But this does not override the inherent margin-left property for the internal class "msgs". How would I change the property for the internal class "msgs" (which is not accessible to me) in order to serve my purpose?

Comment: Couldn't you just do .alert > .msgs { margin-left: 0; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to your global styles.scss file. It selects the div with class *msgs* inside *lib-error-alert-message* element:

```
lib-error-alert-message div.msgs {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

It’s right that you don't have direct access to the library component, but good news is that the global styles.scss is applied to all dom elements.

Comment: Using `!important` is filthy. You should work with specificity instead. If your selector is more specific, it wins.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Angular deep selector - it can be used to target inner component of external libs

```css
:host ::ng-deep {
   lib-error-alert-message div.msgs {
      margin-left: 0;
      width: fit-content;
   }
}
```